# How much space does CoD Advanced Warfare take on 360?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

A friend told me that Advanced Warfare requires an install to play on the Xbox 360, but I can't find out what that is. How much space does it take up no the Xbox 360 hard drive?

If it indeed requires an install, is it possible to partition a portable hard drive that is formatted for Windows? I have a portable hard drive, but no PC, only a Mac, so I don't know how to format it on my computer.

Comment: It does require an install, which is the first CD in the case after you buy it. As for formatting it, I can't help, as I am not good with Macintosh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare requires that your Xbox 360 Hard Drive or an External Drive contain at least 3 GB of free space.

If you need to use an external drive, you should be able to format it to Fat32 or Exfat with Disk Utility on your Mac. Also you can try just plugging it into your Xbox 360 and see if it pops up asking to format it on its own, as sometimes that also works. Keep in mind that by formatting the hard drive it will DELETE EVERYTHING on it first.

Answer (score 0):

My XBox 360S has 3  GB of free space but it still will not load the 2nd disc.   The case says that you need 4 GB of free space, not 3.